# Private messages and machine learning

Tags: getstream-io

I have a few questions:

1. It is possible to implement a "private messages" within GetStream?
   Or, for example, can I combine Getstream API with http://social-stream.dit.upm.es/ ? (this system written on ROR).
2. It is possible to control and change algorithm, how Machine learning works in getstream.io ?

I mean, I found not much information about Machine learning in documentation and getstream account. Maybe I can read about it somewhere in more detail?

3. Machine learning works only on paid plans or in free plan also?
4. getstream.io have specific API for Machine learning purpose?
   For example, if we write some additional features, like "private messages" on our side, which GetStream don't have in API, how we can apply Machine learning on this new features?

You may ask, "why you need a Machine learning for PM"?

Not only PM. Here a few examples:

a) If user have some keyword in PM - we can determine what the topic is interesting to the user.

b) In another scenario - we can analyze images (we use our engine for that purpose) in posts and if some image contain correlation between keywords and specific topic and if we look at who like/vote this image - we can show him more relative content.

c) There is dozens another examples, which we need to control Machine learning process.

5. Even if we implement Machine learning on our side (from zero, just "for private messages" and other related stuff), how we can connect our results in machine learning with results in GetStream? If we will use it separately, it can be inefficient and bring unpredictable results (even negative).

I want to clarify, I am not a developer. I am owner, but understand very well the project management and the entire development process.
My question is a lack of understanding of how the API works.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This post is [too broad](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) for the format of Stack Overflow. Some of this is more of a customer support thing than a programming question but you need to narrow this down. There are some resources on how to write good questions in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: In fact, these questions have been directed to support getstream-io (and have exactly tag). Now I corrected the post and remove unnecessary tags.

Answer (score 1):

Stream helps you build activity streams and newsfeeds. A central aspect of that is the follow relationship. The same building blocks also make it easy to build notification feeds and private messages. Stream isn't build for private messages, but we have dozens of apps using us for that purpose. It works for many apps, but depending on your feature set your milage may vary.

As for your second question. Stream provides scalable newsfeeds, analytics and personalization (machine learning). For larger customers we extensively customize the machine learning component. There are similarities between apps, but it's definitely something which needs to be tailor made. At the moment analytics and personalization are only available to our largest customers. More information can be found here: http://getstream.io/personalization/

Using your own machine learning and Stream's at the same time is pretty easy. You simply track engagement events both in Stream and in your own system. That will allow you to run your own analysis.